# How to represent a nested loop using mathematical formulae

Tags: algorithms, notation

Excluding the context of summation or product, how can one represent a nested loop within mathematical notation?

For instance, if every element of an array X is being compared to one another as part of an algorithm Y, how can this be written? For the purposes of this question, Y is being deliberately kept as an abstract placeholder.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: @5xum oh ok... um... you know nested loops? Like for (i=0;i<n;i++){ for (j=0; j<n;j++) do Y;} How can that be represented in mathematical notation? I have seen sigma used to this effect (double sigma), but sigma exclusively represents summation.

Comment: I still don't get it. What is this 'mathematical notation' you speak of? How would you represent a single, non-nested loop "in mathematical notation"?

Comment: @5xum greek letters and stuff. Example relating to Fibonacci sequence (signle loop, recursive example) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Use_in_mathematics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write down an algorithm, you shouldn't aim to express it as "mathematical formulae" -- by which I assume you mean the kind of symbolic expressions used to write things in algebra or calculus. That notation is *not good for communicating algorithms*, and you will do nobody any favor by trying to cram your algorithm into it. It will be harder to write for you and harder to read for anyone you're trying to communicate with.

Traditionally, when mathematicians needed to speak about algorithms, they described them in *ordinary prose*, sometimes structured as lists of numbered steps or the like.

One of the early insights of computer science was that better notation for algorithms had to be found. An early result of this was ALGOL, which is nowadays remembered as a *programming language*, but was originally conceived as a *way to write down algorithms in papers*. Actual *programs* were at that time much more low-level things, and it was assumed that someone would read the algorithm written down in ALGOL on paper, and then code it up in a real computing language such as assembler or FORTRAN. (The progress of technology almost immediately overtook this assumption when it turned out that ALGOL was well enough specified that actual compilers for it could be made, and it became a programming language).

So the sane thing to use for writing down an algorithm is an *algorithmic notation*. This can either be an actual programming language, or *pseudocode* (which can for most purposes be thought of as being ALGOL but not caring too much about the precise syntax or typography). Pseudocode is often the better choice because it comes with less risk of the *ideas* you want to communicate being obscured by the housekeeping details of a particular programming language.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. Really. However, computer science in academia insists on the usage of greek letters to represent algorithms. Ordinary prose may or may not be included. Pseudocode is actually surprisingly rare. The use of greek letters is typically overloaded such that any single letter may mean multiple things, even within the same context. Typically no legend is provided for these formulae, but meaning is inferred through context and custom. So, attempting to work with this system, I'm looking for a symbol, or style of notation, that conventionally be used to represent such application

Comment: @Stumbler: That does not match my experience as an academic computer scientist -- which was 10 years ago, but I don't think traditions have changed all that much for the worse. Greek letters were certainly employed, but that didn't mean that we tried to cram descriptions of algorithms into symbolisms that were not well suited to it.

Comment: "computer science in academia insists on the usage of Greek letters to represent algorithms" - as an example, can you link us to any recent paper you read that does exactly this, @Stumbler?